# My PC reserves half of my RAM for hardware

Tags: windows, memory, bios, memory-management, msconfig

The problem is basically what the title says. I've been reading a lot of posts where they have the same issue and I tried all the solutions.

These are my specs where you can see I only have half of my RAM available

**System configuration**:

> [image: Screenshot.]

**Task manager**:

> [image: Screenshot.]

I updated the BIOS and Windows and restored the BIOS to default. I tried to put the RAM in the 1-3 slots instead of 2-4 and the same happened. I also tried to put only 1 RAM (one and the other) in the slot and it used 8 GB so it worked great, but when I put both at the same time I get the same issue.

I also unchecked the max capacity option.

**Starting configuration**:

> [image: Screenshot.]

And this is my virtual memory advanced configuration.

> [image: Screenshot.]

A lot of posts in internet are with the same problem and with no solution, can we get the solution in this one?

Comment: Is your memory matched to work together?  Virtual machines use memory but do not affect installed memory. I have 3 machines plus host running here and installed memory says 16 GB, usable 15.8.

Comment: @John The screenshots show a 64 bit OS recognising all 16GiB present... But with over half of that 'reserved for hardware'. It si not a question of EUFI or windows not seeing the memory. @ HttpBelleDefi: anything interesting in the firmware (read EUFI, or sometimes call ed BIOS). Something is reserving the memory, and I know only of two ways outside normal OS: 1. Reserve in firnmware (e.g. for hardware), or limit via msconfig,

Comment: I have not seen a machine reserve 8 GB for hardware. Also since one module (8GB total) did not do that, then I do not think it is a hardware reservation.

Comment: @Hennes I think BIOS is overriding it, I changed the max RAM memory in almost every single configuration option but inside the BIOS I don't see any option to change it neither...

Comment: @Hennes - Do you mean UEFI instead of EUFI?

Comment: Yes (oops). I did mean Unified Extensible Firmware Interface, which has replaced the BIOS on all modern machines.

Comment: Where should I check to modify that? In the BIOS?